# Regular expression: find abc.com except xyz.abc.com or @abc.com

Tags: regex

In Eclipse I want to find a string, and using the normal search results in hundreds of irrelevant results. So I'm trying to use regular expressions, but they don't give me the proper results up til now.

This is what I need: find "abc.com", but not "xyz.abc.com" or "@abc.com". To make it clear, it should return www.abc.com.

I've tried the following regex but I'm not sure if this is how it should be:

```
[^@xyz\.]abc.com
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a negative lookbehind should suit your needs:

```
(?<!xyz[.]|@)abc[.]com
```

*Every "abc.com" that is not preceded by "xyz." nor by "@"*.

Comment: Thank you, but using this expression returns 0 results, while I know there are results. Maybe this has to do with Eclipse?

Comment: @rxt I can make it work in my Eclipse at least. Could you provide the one you tried (i.e. after having replaced `xyz`, `abc`, etc.)?

Comment: Sorry! Stupid me didn't replace abc and xyz! ;-)